# Linux Suse HTTP Port Default Configuration [Enabled/Disabled]

Tags: linux, http, https, suse

I have a question regarding HTTP/HTTPS on Linux SUSE system.

By default, i.e. after installing the operating system, are HTTP/HTTPS ports (80/443) enabled on Linux SUSE? Can I access it through HTTP/HTTPS?

My questions are:

- How to check if HTTP/HTTPS are enabled.
- In case disabled, how to enable.

**P.S.:** I have seen "Apache" in my search but couldn't relate it to the issue at hand.

Your input is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on the installed patterns. The "minimal" OS pattern does not include the http server role, so no apache2 (http server) is going to be installed or activated.

If you install any pattern involving WebYast, then yes, your server will be accessible via HTTP.